# Mysql query to get data which has single quotes in the field data?

Tags: mysql

I have query like this

```
$qry="select * from post_prop 
where project='abinandan's kailash' 
and builder_name='abinandan-foundations-pvt-ltd'";
```

But iam not getting results?

Answer (score 2):

Escape the quotes with double quotes:

```
$qry="select * from post_prop 
where project='abinandan''s kailash' 
and builder_name='abinandan-foundations-pvt-ltd'";
```

You should enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in your `php.ini` and/or remove the `@` in front of your `*_query` command (if present) in order to display errors. This way, PHP would have warned you that there was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_book WHERE (bookname='abinandan\'s kailash' and builder_name='abinandan-foundations-pvt-ltd')";
";
```

Hope it will help you.